# Can not connect to servers following file modifications

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to connect to any server, Minecraft gives an error stating:

> Failed to login: The authentication servers are currently down for
>   maintenance

I accidentally renamed the Servers file while deleting old screen shots.  I have been unable to connect to any server for several days following.  Can the servers file cause this error?

Comment: Which servers file?  servers.dat?  Did you rename it back to the original name?  Did you delete anything else in that directory?

Comment: Just Servers. I havent seen any .dat after files so i honestly have no idea. And yes i did name it back to the original name. I did not delete anyrhing else but the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Over at [mojang](https://help.mojang.com/) you can check the server status. When all services are up, the problem probably exists at your end.
Since you said you deleted some file on accident, try to replace this file (go to your recycle bin and restore the file).
If this doesn't fix it, try reinstalling Minecraft. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have another problem.

The servers file only contains a list of the servers you have added. Even if deleted, it should not cause a connection problem.

I moved the file to see.  I lost my list of servers but could still connect.  When I moved the file back, the servers list is back.  I never had any connectivity issues and the authentication server is up and running.

I recommend reinstalling Minecraft.